# Pandas .replace or .fillna to fill NAN values remedy

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have used pandas excel read operation and merge operation to merge two spreadsheets in the same excel document together into one dataframe. The merged dataframe contains NaN values. I would like to replace/fill the NaN values with data from one of the original spreadsheets in the excel document. Is this possible?

Data details: Historical Sheet

Photo ID| Type| Date|  Location
 1         jpg  5/30/18  USA
 2         jpg  5/30/18  USA
 3         tiff 5/30/18  CAN
 4         tiff 5/30/18  AUS
 5         img  5/30/18  AUS

Current Sheet:
Photo ID| Type| Taken|  Location
 1         jpg  5/30/18  USA
 2         jpg  5/30/18  USA
 3         tiff 5/30/18  CAN
 5         img  5/30/18  AUS

Current Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile

file_location = "H:\\Travel\\AC_Images.xlsx"

test_xls = pd.ExcelFile(file_location)
historical = test_xls.parse("Historical Photos",skiprows=1)
current = test.xls.parse("Current Photos",skiprows=2)

photo_data = historical.merge(current, left_on = "Photo ID", right_on = 
"photonum", how = "left")
photo_data = photo_data[photo_data['Photo ID'].notnull()]
```

Example Return:

Photo ID| Type| Date|  Location
 1         jpg  5/30/18  USA
 2         jpg  5/30/18  USA
 3         tiff 5/30/18  CAN
 4         NaN NaN  NaN  NaN
 5         img  5/30/18  AUS

Again, the merged output contains NaN values. I would like to populate the Date NaN cells with Date values from the Historical Photos sheet in the AC_Images excel document. I tried this:

```
photo_data.replace('NaN', "Historical Photos"["location"])
```

It returned an error "string indicies must be integers." I am not sure how to pull the data from that column and import it in the NaN cells in the merged dataframe. Guidance?

Comment: Can you provide a few lines of data from `historical` and `current` to demonstrate what you need?

Comment: I don't have access to the document atm, but I can create an example. The issue is the historical sheet contains more files and different columns than the current sheet. When I merge the historical with the current, i get NaN values where the data does not overlap. Now I would like to replace the NaN values with data from a column in the historical sheet.

Comment: Have you tried `photo_data['Date'].fillna(historical["Date"])`? or with `Location` the same

Comment: Ben, I haven't but I will give it a try and report back.

Comment: Ben, the process you provided worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ben.T provided the below code that answered my question.

```
photo_data['Date'].fillna(historical["Date"])
```